# Lombok plugin incompatible with 2018.1 Intellij Idea

Tags: intellij-idea, lombok, intellij-lombok-plugin

Right now I have seen Intellij Idea update window with the notion:

> Plugin incompatible with new build found: Lombok Plugin

[image]

Is there a way to solve the problem or I should wait till lombok plugin team resolved the compatibility issues?

Comment: Try updating plugin manually as described here: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/installing-updating-and-uninstalling-repository-plugins.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Intellij fails to detect the logger added by @Slf4j using Lombok](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49548018/intellij-fails-to-detect-the-logger-added-by-slf4j-using-lombok)

Comment: just update your Lombok

Answer (score 111, accepted):

The following is a solution works for me:

1. Update intellij idea (I use the community release zip package)
2. Run Idea and open settings
3. Select lombok plugin and reload list of plugins
   [image]
4. Then there will button <kbd>Update</kbd> instead of <kbd>Uninstall</kbd>. Press it and after updating restart Idea

Have a look at [link](https://github.com/mplushnikov/lombok-intellij-plugin/issues/465) for more information.

Comment: this also solved my issue with the go-plugin, which enables the GoLand feature-set

Comment: Updating Lombok also solved several instances of IntelliJ improperly highlighting what it thought were compile errors.

Comment: Worked on 2018.2! But isn't IDEA supposed to update plugins automatically?

Answer (score 13):

Just uninstall Lombok Plugin and install it again.

Comment: I could not find the options in the selected answer. But, your answer worked well for me. I had updated to Intellij 2020.1 and was getting an error that lombok plugin won't work anymore. Thanks. (PS - Never underestimate the power of restarting, reinstalling etc.)

Answer (score 5):

Adding on to the above answers, because I cannot comment. It is unnecessary to remove Lombok. I didn't see update option at first in plugins list (even after reloading the list), but when you enter 'browse repositories' and search for Lombok there, you should be seeing an update option, as I did.

Don't forget to re-enable annotation processing, which in my case was disabled after the update.

Answer (score 3):

Lombok works in IDEA CE 2018.1 actually, just tried.
Although, you might want to update or remove-then-reinstall that Lombok plugin after upgrading IDEA

```
IntelliJ Lombok plugin 0.15.17.2 
IntelliJ IDEA 2018.1 (Community Edition)
Build #IC-181.4203.550, built on March 27, 2018
macOS 10.13.3
```

Screenshots: [IDEA 2018.1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nvuC6.png) & [Lombok plugin in use](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UHqsC.png)