# Intellij fails to detect the logger added by @Slf4j using Lombok

Tags: java, intellij-idea, slf4j, lombok, intellij-lombok-plugin

I am writing a simple app:

```
@Slf4j
public class MyApp {
    public static void main(String[] argv) {
        log.info("hello world!");
    }
}
```

This code compiles just fine, and indeed, when run I see "hello world!" being logged out. Intellij however doesn't agree this works. I am constantly getting "Cannot resolve symbol log" even though this works and it compiles. Here's what I have done:

1. I have installed the latest Lombok plugin
2. I have enabled annotation processing

All other Lombok annotations seem to work fine.

I am using Intellij 2018.1 Ultimate. Is there something I'm missing here?

Comment: Which version of the IDEA Lombok plugin are you using?

Comment: 0.16.2017.3.3 is the version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this one! Either wait till lombok plugin supports `Intellij 2018.1` or downgrade the IDE.

[image]

EDIT:

Above answer is outdated and issue can be fixed by following [this anwer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49530465/lombok-plugin-incompatible-with-2018-1-intellij-idea/49531561#49531561).

Comment: Wow guess I wasn't paying attention when I upgraded. Weird that it would break it this way.